# Trying to create a method that chooses a random method from that same class

Tags: ruby, oop, methods

Maybe this is a stupid idea... I am new to Ruby (and to OOP, so I still dont really know what I am doing most of the time), and I thought of a small, fun project to build, and I am struggling with some concepts.

What I am building is basically a string manipulator. I am building a module with extra methods, and then including that on the String class.

My module has several methods that manipulate the strings in different ways, mostly replacing words, and then return the modified string.

What I want to do in order to make the string manipulation more 'spontaneous' and natural, is to create a "main" method (the one I will be calling from the strings), that randomly selects one of the string manipulation methods, and then returns the string (and then can be called again to apply several manipulations in one go)

How can I do this, or something similar? Hope I explained myself

Thanks

O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the random manipulation module, as you described it.  `something_random` is the *main* method:

```
module RandomStringManipulation

  def something_random
    methods = RandomStringManipulation.instance_methods
    methods -= [:something_random]
    send methods.sample    # Ruby >= 1.9 required.  See below for Ruby 1.8.
  end

  def foo
    self + "foo"
  end

  def bar
    self + "bar"
  end

end
```

Mix it into `String`:

```
class String
  include RandomStringManipulation
end
```

Now we can create an empty string, and then do something random to it a few times, printing it out each time:

```
s = ""
4.times do
  s = s.something_random
  p s
end

# => "foo"
# => "foobar"
# => "foobarbar"
# => "foobarbarfoo"
```

---

There are two bits that are interesting.  The first is this:

```
methods -= [:something_random]
```

That removes `:something_random` from the array `methods`, preventing the *something_random* method from calling itself.  The second interesting bit is this:

```
send methods.sample
```

`Array.sample` (Ruby >= 1.9) selects a random method.  `send` then dispatches that method.  In Ruby 1.8, do this instead:

```
send methods[rand(methods.size)]
```

Comment: Thanks Wayne, that is very useful. Your answer is very useful to me, but I had to accept one of these two and Mark's was easier to understand, but yours made me learn some new stuff. Thanks

Comment: Just realized, the other code didnt work and I ended uo having to use yours, so I changed the accepted answer

Comment: @0al0, I'm glad it worked for you.  There is part of Mark Reed's answer that's better than anything I just wrote: he admonishes you to be wary of monkey-patching String.  That's good advice.  There are pitfalls there: imagine some gem also monkey patching String.  When your monkey patch conflicts with someone else's, you'll wish you were never born.  It can be a real pain.

Comment: I know, I read about that, but this is a very small project I am doing for fun and do not intend to reuse it or anything, so it shouldnt be a problem

Answer (score 4):

If all the code that will be using your functionality is your code, I would make a new class instead of monkey-patching String.  Monkey-patching leads to code that is harder to understand and share.

Anyway, given a list of mutator methods, you can easily pick one at random and use Object#send to call it:

```
module StringMutator
   def fold() ... end
   def spindle() ... end
   def mutilate() ... end
end

class NiftyString
  include StringMutator
  def random_change() 
    im = StringMutator.instance_methods
    self.send im[rand im.length]
  end
end
```